# ImportError: No module named _collections

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-module

Right after a fresh install, when 
`python get-pip.py --user` I get this error about `_collections`.
From the python prompt I can import basic stuff such as `os` and `sys` but not `time`.

my environment (done by hand sourcing a script) is such that

```
~>echo $PYTHONPATH
~/python2715/lib/python2.7/:~/python2715/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

and

```
~>echo $PYTHONHOME
~/python2715/lib/python2.7/:~/python2715/lib/python2.7/site-packages/

~>which python
~/python2715/bin/python

~>python --version
Python 2.7.15
```

Any suggestions as of why I cannot import modules? any other env variable to check?

Comment: Can you do: `which python`, and `python --version`?

Comment: of course relevant. added in the edited post.

Comment: I couldn't find anything similar online to what you're seeing. Can you send the full output of `python get-pip.py --user`?

Comment: It should be `export $PYTHONHOME=~/python2715/`

Comment: I don't understand where you're getting at with your last comment. FYI, you should omit the `$` when assigning variables in bash.

Comment: sorry that `$` was a mistake. I am saying that my problem was the value of `PYTHONHOME`, which should be set to the same thing I used as `--prefix` in configure. In my case `export PYTHONHOME=~/python2715/`. This fixes my problem.

Comment: FWIW You shouldn't need to set PYTHONHOME (which should be a single directory not a colon separated list). It should match where you installed it assuming you actually built it with `--prefix=~/python2714` as you stated.

Comment: On other systems I think I have seen Python working without explicitly setting PYTHONHOME, you stand correct.